# Storing DateTimes in 30 min intervals to array

Tags: c#

My objective is to populate a combo box with time intervals of 30 min for 24 hours. I.E - 12.00am, 12.30am,  1.00am, 1.30am and so on.  I need to know how to put these details into array.  Thank you

Comment: How do you save them exactly? As a string?

Comment: I'm not too sure.  The combobox is there for users to select the start time of an appointment.  So that value will be stored to a list after being selected as a DateTime.  I am a 1st year network student that is pretty poor at programming.  Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: Why are people -1'ing without bothering to post a reason? +1'ing just to cancel em out. Sheesh... people these days....

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
string[] comboboxDataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 2 * 24)
    .Select(min => DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(30 * min).ToString("h.mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Tim, wouldn't be better to use `h` instead of `hh` since looks like OP doesn't want leading zero for single digit hour?

Comment: @SonerGönül: you're right. I have already noticed it from OP's desired format and fixed it.

Comment: I'm having problems with 'CultureInfo'  'does not exist in the current context'

Comment: You either have to use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` or add `using System.Globalization;` to the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to iterate `30` minutes in a day and add this `DateTime` values with a specific string representation to your list. Like;

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
DateTime start = DateTime.Today;
DateTime end = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

while (end > start)
{
    list.Add(start.ToString("h.mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    start = start.AddMinutes(30);
}
```

If you wanna get them as an array, just use `list.ToArray()` to get it. Also time designators are in .NET Framework are mostly (I haven't check all of them) upper case. That means, you will get `AM` or `PM` when you use `tt` specifier, not `am` or `pm`. In such a case, you need to replace these values with their lower cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you mean. I would start with something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Timespan> Get30MinuteIntervalls()
{
  var currentValue = new Timespan(0);
  while (currentValue <= Timespan.FromHours(24)
  {
    yield return currentValue;
    currentValue = currentValue.Add(Timespan.FromMinutes(30));
  } 
}

var values = Get30MinuteIntervalls().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var d = new DateTime();
  d = d.Date.AddHours("0").AddMinutes("0");
  for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
  {
        d.AddMinutes(30);
        cbo.AddItem(d.TimeOfDay.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: This is wrong in many parts. First, AddHours accepts double as a paremeter, not a string. Second, you don't need `AddHours` and `AddMinutes`, as they do nothing useful if the parameters are zero. In your for loop, you add 30 Minutes to `d`, but you don't use the return value of `AddMinutes` anywhere, but instead add the oridinal `d` to the combobox.